# Unable to select 4k in Ubuntu, works in Windows

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have a dual boot Dell Inspiron 17-7700, with Nvidia GeForce 940MX. I plan on buying a 4k monitor, but I wanted to test if it actually worked on my laptop. The display I am trying to connect to is AOC U2790PQU.

In windows everyting works fine. When changing to Ubuntu I am unable to select 4k resolution.

```
xrandr
```

only shows up to 1920x1080. Creating a custom profile did not work:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "Mode 0" --verbose
screen 0: 3840x2160 1013x570 mm  96.25dpi
crtc 1:       Mode 0  60.00 +0+0 "HDMI-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

I've tried using a Ubuntu Live USB to see if it was my installation (I mess around a lot, and I was thinking maybe i3 was the problem). This did also not work.

I've resorted to changing x.org files and adding modlines as mentioned [here (4k@60hz on linux)](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/7w4tnv/how_i_got_my_4k_monitor_working_at_60hz_in_linux/).
This outputs the same error as above (configure crtc 1 failed).

Changing graphics driver (in Software center - Additional Drivers) from Nouveau to NVIDIA driver metapackage nvidia-driver-435 (proprietary, tested) did not help.

Relevant information (I'm of course not sure if this is everthing, tell me if something is missing):

```
sudo lshw -C video 
  *-display 
       description: VGA compatible controller 
       product: HD Graphics 620 
       vendor: Intel Corporation 
       physical id: 2 
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 
       version: 02 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
       resources: irq:145 memory:d4000000-d4ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff 
  *-display UNCLAIMED 
       description: 3D controller 
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX] 
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
       version: a2 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list 
       configuration: latency=0 
       resources: memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
```

-

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted rig 
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.07 
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88 
   1600x1024     60.17 
   1400x1050     59.98 
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82 
   1280x1024     60.02 
   1440x900      59.89 
   1400x900      59.96    59.88 
   1280x960      60.00 
   1440x810      60.00    59.97 
   1368x768      59.88    59.85 
   1360x768      59.80    59.96 
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91 
   1152x864      60.00 
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74 
   1024x768      60.04    60.00 
   960x720       60.00 
   928x696       60.05 
   896x672       60.01 
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82 
   960x600       59.93    60.00 
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82 
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25 
   840x525       60.01    59.88 
   864x486       59.92    59.57 
   800x512       60.17 
   700x525       59.98 
   800x450       59.95    59.82 
   640x512       60.02 
   720x450       59.89 
   700x450       59.96    59.88 
   640x480       60.00    59.94 
   720x405       59.51    58.99 
   684x384       59.88    59.85 
   680x384       59.80    59.96 
   640x400       59.88    59.98 
   576x432       60.06 
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32 
   512x384       60.00 
   512x288       60.00    59.92 
   480x270       59.63    59.82 
   400x300       60.32    56.34 
   432x243       59.92    59.57 
   320x240       60.05 
   360x202       59.51    59.13 
   320x180       59.84    59.32 
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x ax 
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94* 
   1680x1050     59.88 
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02 
   1440x900      59.90 
   1280x960      60.00 
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94 
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00 
   832x624       74.55 
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25 
   720x576       50.00 
   720x480       60.00    59.94 
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94 
   720x400       70.08 
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

-

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid 
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun. 
Attempting to use i2c interface 
No EDID on bus 0 
No EDID on bus 2 
No EDID on bus 4 
No EDID on bus 5 
No EDID on bus 6 
2 potential busses found: 1 3 
Will scan through until the first EDID is found. 
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one. 
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 1 
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day. 
Checksum Correct 
Section "Monitor" 
        Identifier "U2790B" 
        ModelName "U2790B" 
        VendorName "AOC" 
        # Monitor Manufactured week 38 of 2019 
        # EDID version 1.3 
        # Digital Display 
        DisplaySize 600 340 
        Gamma 2.20 
        Option "DPMS" "true" 
        Horizsync 30-160 
        VertRefresh 23-80 
        # Maximum pixel clock is 600MHz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 60Hz 
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz 
        #Extension block found. Parsing... 
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 93) 
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 94) 
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 95) 
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 96) 
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 97) 
        Modeline        "Mode 9" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 0" 533.25 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 262.75 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2191 +hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 5" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 6" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 7" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 8" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 10" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 11" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 12" 277.25 1920 1968 2000 2080 2160 2163 2173 2222 +hsync -vsync 
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 9" 
EndSection
```

I am out of ideas. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of solved it.

For anyone running in the same problem:
I manually installed a NVidia driver, none of the ppa ones were working.
For that I followed the instructions [here. (Nvidia driver installs but does not load on ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133823)
NVidia was now working, but still no 4k.
Turns out it was not simply 30fps, but the pixel clock needed to be reduced ([Can't set correct display resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410813))

I think the problem is not completely fixed, because my GPU "should be able to support" 4k@60fps. GeForce 940MX is a very weird model and I do not advise it to anyone. Even NVidia themselves are unclear about 4k support.